# Simple User Input for CodeHS in Java

Tags: java

> Write a program that takes in user input to ask the following
>   questions:
>
> “What is your favorite food?”
>   “What is your favorite color?”
>   “What is your favorite movie?”
>
> After asking these three questions, print out the answers on their own
>   lines.
>
> An example output would look like this:
>
> ```
> pasta
> green
> The Lego Movie
> ```

So far, I have this. However it says I did not print the correct number of lines.

```
public class AboutYou extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        String favFood = readLine("What is your favorite food? ");

        String favColor = readLine("What is your favorite color? ");

        String favMovie = readLine("What is your favorite movie? ");

    }
}
```

and this is my output:

```
What is your favoirte food? tofu
What is your favorite color? green
What is your favorite movie? movie
```

Comment: What says that you did not print out the right number of lines? Do you have an automated grader or something that is judging this assignment?

Comment: That's the input. You're missing the output. Look at the example output. After your `readLine` code, you need to print `favFood` by itself, then `favColor`, then `favMovie`.

Comment: Yes it is an automated grader but it does not give you all the specifics. Thank you for your help, your solution worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to that problem statement, you're missing the print-out of the answers afterwards. There should be a total of 6 lines when you look at the console afterwards:

```
What is your favoirte food? tofu
What is your favorite color? green
What is your favorite movie? movie
tofu
green
movie
```

You probably want to add some print statements where you print out the variables `favFood`, `favColor`, and `favMovie` each on their own line.